# Check if all players are ready

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I need help to loop through a player's object and check if all players are ready.

I have a javascript object called `players` with the player object that contains a few properties. One of them is `ready`. My target is to log to the console "All players are now ready" when all players `ready` property is true.

```
players = {
  vGlAIs9Nn8viAFQ4AAAA: {
    playerId: 'vGlAIs9Nn8viAFQ4AAAA',
    alive: true,
    ready: true
  },
  c1Acl3kLSUuge0p4AAAB: {
    playerId: 'c1Acl3kLSUuge0p4AAAB',
    alive: true,
    ready: false
  },
  '5nyDlUPtWrYg31EEAAAC': {
    playerId: '5nyDlUPtWrYg31EEAAAC',
    alive: true,
    ready: false
  }
}
```

Comment: You might wanna take a look at the `Object.keys()` method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
You'll be able to loop on your players ;)

Comment: As you've already mentioned the `for` loop... What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: `Object.keys()` / `Object.entries()` + `Array.prototype.every()`

Comment: `Object.values(players).every(player => player.ready)`

Comment: Edit: Array.some() seems better for your case. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Array.every

```js
const players = {
  vGlAIs9Nn8viAFQ4AAAA: {
    playerId: 'vGlAIs9Nn8viAFQ4AAAA',
    alive: true,
    ready: true
  },
  c1Acl3kLSUuge0p4AAAB: {
    playerId: 'c1Acl3kLSUuge0p4AAAB',
    alive: true,
    ready: false
  },
  '5nyDlUPtWrYg31EEAAAC': {
    playerId: '5nyDlUPtWrYg31EEAAAC',
    alive: true,
    ready: false
  }
};

const values = Object.values(players);

const isReady = values.every(item => !!item.ready);

console.log(isReady);
```

Comment: @charbelk I don't understand by "un-ready" can you please explain more ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is function that returns a Boolean when the condition is met;

```js
function isEveryoneReady (obj) {
  return Object.values(obj).every(player => player.ready)
}
```

check the example in code snippet below:

```js
function isEveryoneReady (obj) {
  return Object.values(obj).every( player => {
    return player.ready
  })
}

notReadyPlayers = {
  vGlAIs9Nn8viAFQ4AAAA: {
    playerId: 'vGlAIs9Nn8viAFQ4AAAA',
    alive: true,
    ready: true
  },
  c1Acl3kLSUuge0p4AAAB: {
    playerId: 'c1Acl3kLSUuge0p4AAAB',
    alive: true,
    ready: false
  },
  '5nyDlUPtWrYg31EEAAAC': {
    playerId: '5nyDlUPtWrYg31EEAAAC',
    alive: true,
    ready: false
  }
}

readyPlayers = {
  vGlAIs9Nn8viAFQ4AAAA: {
    playerId: 'vGlAIs9Nn8viAFQ4AAAA',
    alive: true,
    ready: true
  },
  c1Acl3kLSUuge0p4AAAB: {
    playerId: 'c1Acl3kLSUuge0p4AAAB',
    alive: true,
    ready: true
  },
  '5nyDlUPtWrYg31EEAAAC': {
    playerId: '5nyDlUPtWrYg31EEAAAC',
    alive: true,
    ready: true
  }
}


console.log(isEveryoneReady(notReadyPlayers))
console.log(isEveryoneReady(readyPlayers))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const players = {
  vGlAIs9Nn8viAFQ4AAAA: {
    playerId: 'vGlAIs9Nn8viAFQ4AAAA',
    alive: true,
    ready: true
  },
  c1Acl3kLSUuge0p4AAAB: {
    playerId: 'c1Acl3kLSUuge0p4AAAB',
    alive: true,
    ready: false
  },
  '5nyDlUPtWrYg31EEAAAC': {
    playerId: '5nyDlUPtWrYg31EEAAAC',
    alive: true,
    ready: false
  }
}

if (Object.values(players).every(item => item.ready)) {
  console.log('All players are ready.')
} else {
  console.log('Some or all players are not yet ready');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let all_ready = true;
for (const player of players) {
  if (!player.ready) {
    all_ready = false;
    break;
  }
}
if (all_ready) {
  console.log("All players are now ready!");
}
```